# "Attempt to serve directory:" Nagios throwing errors through httpd error log

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, nagios

I am trying to install Nagios on a centos vm on Ec2 from yum.

When trying to restart httpd to get Nagios up I was hit with this bug form the http error log

```
Attempt to serve directory: /usr/share/nagios/html/
```

This is my nagios.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName nagios.xx.com
        ServerAlias nagios.xx.com

        ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin/ /usr/lib64/nagios/cgi-bin/
        <Directory /usr/lib64/nagios/cgi-bin/>
           Options ExecCGI
           order deny,allow
           deny from all
           allow from 127.0.0.1
           AuthType Basic
           AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/passwd
           AuthName "nagios"
           require valid-user
        </Directory>

        Alias / /usr/share/nagios/html/
        <Directory /usr/share/nagios/html/>
           Options None
           order deny,allow
           deny from all
           allow from 127.0.0.1
           AuthType Basic
           AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
           AuthName "nagios"
           require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the html directory perm

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 apache apache 4096 Jun 20 17:53 html
```

The parent directories have perms like this

nagios

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:53 nagios
```

share

```
drwxr-xr-x 103 root root  4096 Jun 20 17:53 share
```

usr

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 Feb 24 16:30 usr
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What version of Nagios are you running?

Comment: newest versions of Nagios have PHP code instead of cgi-bin perl, so your ScriptAlias would be wrong and a DirectoryIndex index.php would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Alias / /usr/share/nagios/html/` with `DocumentRoot /usr/share/nagios/html/` if you want to run it from the / of your domain.

Btw you know you can only access the directory from your local box with `allow from 127.0.0.1`, right? (unless you use this to reverse-proxy)

Comment: Checking the date of this question **after** posting I feel like a grave-digger ....